# ADFS 3, Create a Rule to Send Group Membership as a Claim

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs3.0

I am trying to send a few groups memberships as a claim on ADFS3 to a cloud relying party.

I am using a Microsoft article (Below) to Create a Rule to Send Group Membership as a Claim.  the MS article says under Claim rule template, select Send Group Membership as Claim and then after giving a name to the rule and selecting a group from the Active Directory, it does not specify what to choose for "Outgoing Claim type" and what to enter in "Outgoing Claim Value" box.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-rule-to-send-group-membership-as-a-claim

Thanks,
Majid

Answer (score 1):

The following custom rules worked.

```
      @RuleName = "Add Group Claims"
                     c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", 
                     Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
                      => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://test.com/phase1"), query = 
                     ";memberOf;{0}", param = c.Value);

                     @RuleName = "Edit Group"
                     c:[Type == "http://test.com/phase1"]
                      => add(Type = "http://test.com/phase2", Value = RegExReplace(c.Value, ",[^\n]*", ""));

                     @RuleName = "Remove CN from Group"
                     c:[Type == "http://test.com/phase2"]
                      => add(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", Value = RegExReplace(c.Value, 
                     "^CN=", ""));

                     @RuleName = "Send Only Groups Containing ADFS"
                     c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", Value =~ "(?i)Groups-prefix"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you wanted to pass AD group "isAdmin".

The first part is selecting that group in AD.

Then decide on a group name (e.g. http://company.com/Admin) and then a group value (e.g. isAdmin).

Then if the user is a member of that group, you will get a claim:

http://company.com/Admin/isAdmin

Comment: Thanks for responding to my inquiry. In the ADFS3 UI, there are four fields 1.claim Rule Name ( I believe I can give any names) 2. User's group ( I can select from AD) 3. Outgoing claim Type ( needs to be chosen from the dropdown menu, I have no idea what to choose ) 4. Outgoing claim value ( if I understand it right,  the value is the name of the AD group). could you comment on these fields. thanks.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Yes 3) You can type a meaningful name in the box 4)You can type anything but yes, the name of the AD group is good practice

Comment: Just to note, groups are normally sent as a claim type of Role.